# MongoDB Aggregation of Time Series

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB to store time series data using a similar structure to "The Document-Oriented Design" explained here: [http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb][1]
The data is sparse, not periodical; example can be seen below:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId(),
        "sensor_hw" : "somesensor",
        "day" : ISODate("2017-06-22T00:00:00Z"),
        "0" : {  // hour
                 "0" : {  // minute
                          "0": [1, 2, 3],  //second: measures [x, y, z]
                          "1": [1, 2, 3],
                          "2": [1, 2, 3],
                          ...
                 },  
                 "1" : {
                          "0": [1, 2, 3],
                          "1": [1, 2, 3],
                          "2": [1, 2, 3],
                          ...
                 },  
                 ...
        },
        "1" : {  // hour
                 "2" : {  // minute
                          "3": [1, 2, 3],  //second
                          "10": [1, 2, 3],
                          "15": [1, 2, 3],
                          ...
                 },  
                 ...
        },
                .
                .
                .
   }
```

I would like to aggreagate these time series directly with mongodb to obtain a flatten structure which can eventually be limited to a time frame, similar to:

```
{
    timestamp:  ISODate("2017-06-22T00:00:01Z"),
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
},
...
{
    timestamp:  ISODate("2017-06-22T01:02:03Z"),
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
}
```

What's the most efficent way to obtain this?

Comment: The whole point of this sort of structure is to hold "pre-aggregated" data, which you "collect" as you write. If you think you need to run a further aggregation over it, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What's suggested to be able to plot for example the last 30min of the data?

Comment: The idea and why you have all the named keys there is so as you increment each minute, you also write to hour and to day or whatever your interval pattern is. The most recent MongoDB has tools to deal with named keys in the aggregation framework, and all versions can aggregate via map reduce. But if you read somewhere to store data like this in the first place, then you really need to understand why you are doing it. If you don't actually understand, then it's the wrong format for you. Store in plain documents and/or arrays instead.